# Objects which are points imply categorical products $X\times Y$ have Cartesian product as underlying set?

Tags: category-theory

Suppose you have a small category $\mathcal{C}$ which happens to have at least one object $\{\ast\}$ whose underlying set is just a singleton set. Does this always imply that the categorical product of any two objects $X\times Y$ has the Cartesian product, denote it say $X\times_{cart} Y$, as its underlying set?

By the definition of product, don't we have in $\mathsf{Set}$,
$$
X\times Y\cong\operatorname{Hom}(\{\ast\},X\times Y)\cong\operatorname{Hom}(\{\ast\},X)\times\operatorname{Hom}(\{\ast\},Y)\cong X\times_{cart} Y
$$

Is this true, or maybe I am overlooking something?

Comment: The first sentence of the question implicitly assumes that $\mathcal C$ is a concrete category, so that "underlying set" makes sense.  In the next sentence, you've tacitly identified objects $X$ and $Y$ with their underlying sets, so that $X\times_{cart}Y$ makes sense.  You should probably say explicitly what you're assuming, as it can affect the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is imprecise: at several points you mix up objects and their underlying sets. Here is a precise version:

> Suppose $(C, F)$ is a [concrete category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_category), that is, a pair consisting of a category $C$ and a faithful functor $F : C \to \text{Set}$ (the "underlying set" functor). Further suppose there is an object $c \in C$ such that $F(c)$ is the one-element set. Does it follow that $F$ preserves products in the sense that $F(X \times Y) \cong F(X) \times F(Y)$?

The answer is no. Here's a somewhat contrived counterexample: take $C = \text{Set}$ and take $F$ to be the covariant powerset functor, sending a set $X$ to the set $2^X$ of subsets of $X$ and sending a map of sets to the direct image. The "underlying set" of the empty set has one element, but this functor does not respect products.

The condition you want, which makes your argument go through, is that $c$ represents the functor $F$ in the sense that we have a natural isomorphism

$$F(-) \cong \text{Hom}(c, -).$$

With this hypothesis, which most natural examples satisfy, $F$ will in fact preserve all limits, not just products. But this condition doesn't have much to do with the underlying set of $c$ having one element; for example, when $C = \text{Ab}$ we have $c = \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I think I didn't know what I was talking about. I was motivated by reading that the underlying set of a product of prevarieties has the cartesian product as its underlying set. Many authors, like Borel, just say, take $W$ to be a prevariety consisting of a point, then $$Hom(W,X\times Y)\cong Hom(W,X)\times Hom(W,Y),$$ and each of these spaces can be identified with the underlying sets of $X\times Y$, $X$, and $Y$, resp. Is that line of thinking similarly imprecise?

Comment: @Denise: that's an example of what I'm talking about in the second half of the answer. To avoid confusion I'll refer to "the point," as a variety, as $\text{Spec } k$. Then $\text{Spec } k$ represents the forgetful functor sending a variety over $k$ to its underlying set of $k$-points. The fact that $\text{Spec } k$ itself has underlying set a point reflects the additional fact that $\text{Spec } k$ is the terminal object of the category of varieties over $k$. But that's not what powers the argument that taking $k$-points preserves products. (For example, $\mathbb{Z}$ is not terminal.)